# Angular 4+ conditionally render mat-menu (all or some mat menu options)

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material

Ello,

I am rendering a mat-table and each row has an eclipse (3 dots) that displays a mat-menu. Right now, every row clicked shows the same menu option say

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

My row has additional data and I'd like to use said data to display all list items, or some.

I tried using ngIf inside one of the mat-menu options, but no cigar

```
     <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" >
        <ng-template matMenuContent let-someId="someId" let-eventOtherId="eventitherId" let-testcondition="condition">
          <a href="" *ngIf="testcondition === 'some item'"  mat-menu-item [routerLink]="[]">
            <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
            <span>List Item 1</span>
          </a>
          <button mat-menu-item (click)="openDialog([someId])">
            <mat-icon>save_alt</mat-icon>
            <span>List Item 2</span>
          </button>
          <button  mat-menu-item (click)="openDialog([someId])">
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            <span>List Item 3</span>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-menu>
```

so ideally, I'd like to display list item 1 if testcondition === 'some item' and render list item 2 if testcondition === 'some other item'

**edit: After digging around some more, it turns out out that *let-testcondition="condition"* doesn't evaluate to anything. testcondition should have a value associated with it (from the condition property which I can see in my console) but in the ng-container no value for testcondition even though someId and eventOtherId have a value. Any help on using let variable inside template would be much appreciated**

Comment: You should use the *ngIf directive on the DOM elements you wan't to be or not displayed. Based on the code you shared, List Item 2 and 3 will always display, as there is no structural directive (for example *ngIf) on any of them.

Comment: I understand that. Upon further digging around, it looks like let testcondition="condition" is not evaluating to anything so List Item 1 (in this example since that's the element I am conditionally displaying) never renders.

Comment: So what is wrong with `*ngIf`?

Comment: I just clarified saying the issue isn't *ngIf, it's my ng-template let-testcondition="condition". Technically, *ngIf works correctly by not rendering List Item 1 since testcondition is evaluating to null and/or undefined.